# change world in owlready2

Tags: python, sparql, ontology, owlready

I have some ontologies in multiple directories. each directory contains some ontology like (1_1.owl, 1_2.owl, ...). and I want to query on them in a for loop. for the first ontology in each directory everything is OK but for other ontologies in same directory query works and works and nothing returns. I think in each loop, each ontology adds to existing ontology and query takes much time because of size of ontology.
how can flush world after each loop? I create a world using:

```
ont = get_ontology(graph).load()
```

and query the ontology using:

```
list(default_world.sparql(query))[0][0])
```

this codes run in a for loop.

Comment: You probably need to create a new world for each new ontology, see https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/v0.32/world.html